# Pandas mutiply a column by (-1) using another column's valuea as a condition

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I have a data frame with 2 columns one is named NP_x and has values NaN and 'X' and the other one is Amount_x and have int values. What I try to do is that I want to multiply the amount with (-1) where NP_x ='X'

For examnple
I have

```
NP_x   Amount_x
X       2
        5
X       4
X       3
```

I want to obtain

```
NP_x   Amount_x
X       -2
        5
X       -4
X       -3
```

I tried to do this:

```
df.loc[df_query5['NP_x'] == 'X', 'Amount_x'] = df['Amount_x'].multiply(-1)
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

```
import numpy as np
df['Amount_x'] = np.where(df['NP_x']=='X',df['Amount_x']*-1,df['Amount_x'])
```

Answer (score 2):

There you go using mul (mutiply) operator :

```
df.loc[df['NP_x'] == 'X', 'Amount_x'] = df['Amount_x'].mul(-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

See: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html

```
>>> df.loc[df['shield'] > 6, ['max_speed']]
            max_speed
sidewinder          7
```

Therefore, you can use the following code:
`df.loc[df['NP_x'] == 'X', ['Amount_x']] = - df.loc[df['NP_x'] == 'X', ['Amount_x']]`

Answer (score 0):

look my example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([["X", 2], ["Y", 3], ["X", 5]], columns=list("AB"))
```

> df:
>
> ```
>   A   B
> 0 X   2
> 1 Y   3
> 2 X   5
> ```

```
df["B"] = df["B"].mask(df["A"]=="X", -df["B"])
```

> df:
>
> ```
> A B
> 0 X   -2
> 1 Y    3
> 2 X   -5
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[df['NP_x']=='X', 'Amount_x'] *= -1
```

working same like:

```
df.loc[df['NP_x']=='X', 'Amount_x'] = df.loc[df['NP_x']=='X', 'Amount_x'] * -1
```